# Online liter scale generator?

Tags: web-apps

I would like to generate custom liter scale to put on non cylindrical plastic container (fermenter).

I've measured each liter and have an exact position of it.

I want to avoid using Illustrator etc. because I believe that there is an easier way to do it.

Output I want to achieve is like this:

[image]